# Mobile Safari SVG Problem

Tags: iphone, svg, mobile-safari

I'm trying to get an SVG image to show up on my iPhone (or iPad) default browser, but I can't seem to get even just a rect to show up.

Example at: http://www.invalidpage.com/svg/svgtest.html

Source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-us">
  <head>
    <title>SVG iPhone Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <svg width="500" height="220">
        <rect x="2" y="2" width="496" height="216" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2px" fill="transparent"></rect>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at the examples here for how to get started with SVG: http://croczilla.com/bits_and_pieces/svg/samples/ Here are some simple examples that illustrate how to include inline SVG content in XHTML: http://croczilla.com/bits_and_pieces/svg/samples/dom1/dom1.xml http://croczilla.com/bits_and_pieces/svg/samples/dom2/dom2.xml

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Add `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"` to your svg tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-us">
  <head>
    <title>SVG iPhone Test</title>
  </head>
<body >
      <svg width="500" height="220" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
        <rect x="2" y="2" width="496" height="216" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2px" fill="transparent"></rect>
      </svg>


</body>
</html>
```

The HTTP MIME type being delivered by `http://www.invalidpage.com/svg/svgtest.html` is 
`"Content-Type: text/html"`. HTML inline svg works with the MIME type `"Content-Type: text/xml"` You can create this by ending the document with XML instead of HTML as they have [done here](https://developer.mozilla.org/presentations/xtech2005/svg-canvas/SVGDemo.xml).

Not sure if Ipad cares about the `Content-Type` but other browsers do.

***Updated***

```
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
```

Can also be used; It is what is being shown on the Ipad svg examples. When the document is delivering as an XML not HTML, it should start with `<xml version="1.0" standalone="no">`;

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>

<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">


      <svg width="500" height="220" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
        <rect x="2" y="2" width="496" height="216" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2px" fill="transparent"></rect>
      </svg>
```

Comment: Actually, the way it is it works on everything except the iPad/iPhone as far as I can tell. I plugged in RaphaelJS and it's working on iOS now too. I also did try the xmlns and version attributes, same result, works everywhere except iOS.

Comment: It does render in Chrome which uses webkit engine (so Ipad should render - I don't yet have one): But not currently working in firefox 3.6.13 ... That is likely because content type is "Content-Type: text/html" ... under strict xml rules xmlns needs to be defined. <!DOCTYPE html> does not apply strict xml rules however firefox 3.6.13 unfortunately still does not render <!DOCTYPE html> inline svg.  ... by using http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/ it will also work in Internet Explorer

Comment: I know it theoretically should work in any webkit browser if it works in one. It just doesn't. I've switched all the stuff around in another page on my primary domain to test all the different options you've presented, and none work. The only thing that seems to work is generating it post-load through JavaScript. I've left the original page alone so that it still matches the original question.

Comment: I couldn't get this to load on an iPhone even with JS post-load. Any clue?

Comment: The 'standalone' bit seems to be quite important: my images with svg sources where getting squashed when changing the `src` attribute with jQuery on an iPad 1. Adding 'standalone' solved this.

Comment: Safari may use webkit, just the same as Chrome & Opera, but Safari is also Mac & functions very differently, as does Opera. Just because it works in one webkit, doesn't always means it works in another.

Answer (score 14):

Figured I would tack this on here, though it's mostly just related to the title.

I had my SVG tag rendering everything properly in every browser (even IE9+), except for iOS. I had the css height of the svg set to 100%, which worked everywhere, but on iOS it appeared to be 100% of the height of the entire page, instead of just its parent element! This was causing my inner SVG elements to render outside of their viewport.

Adding a `position: absolute` to the svg tag fixed my issue and it rendered properly on iOS and everywhere else (the parent element was already positioned, so this didn't change the actual position of the svg). Other position styles may also work.

Comment: I had a similar issue to yours. Mine was simply solved with adding a "position: relative" to both the parent and the container of the svg.

Comment: The problem is the lack of positioning context of the parent's region. Most browsers tend to cascade the positioning context as default, but it seems iOS doesn't, at least for SVG.

As soon as you give its parent some context (be it 'relative', 'absolute' or 'static'), it then acknowledges what the dimensions of its context are - and then it can correctly relate to the 100% of the parent.

More about css positioning here: http://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101

Answer (score 5):

I have had this problem before too with mobile Safari. What you can do is load the SVG into the the DOM via javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var svg = '<svg width="500" height="220" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"><rect x="2" y="2" width="496" height="216" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2px" fill="transparent"></rect></svg>';
    var chart = document.adoptNode($('svg', $.parseXML(svg)).get(0));

    $('body').html(chart);
);
```

That's just an example - obviously you're not going to store your SVG in a string like that in practice.

You could retrieve the SVG string from the server via ajax, and then load into the DOM using the above approach if you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

I also had a problem displaying large SVGS (dimensions) in IOS browsers. By scaling it down I did get it to work.

I think around 1000px and down will do it..
A friend of mine told me it perhaps had something to with Integer Limits for IOS.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7fh3a000.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Mixing SVG tags with HTML tags without using a well-formed XHTML document and namespaces (see Wayne's answer) is not supported in Safari for iOS 4.2.1 and earlier, nor is it supported in Safari 5.0.x and earlier on Mac OS X and Windows.

Including SVG tags within an HTML document is a new feature of HTML5 parsers.  If you download and run a [nightly build of WebKit](http://nightly.webkit.org/) for Mac OS X or Windows, you'll see that your test case works as expected.

Comment: Isn't the iPhone supposed to be fully HTML5 compatible, or is the native SVG processing not part of the HTML5 standard?

Comment: @md5sum: HTML5 is still a draft specification at this point (to be completed in 2014, apparently), so "HTML5 compliant" is a loose term. The mobile safari browser supports some features of HTML5, but not others. Inline SVG is part of the HTML5 draft specification, but is not yet included in the mobile safari browser. Examples of parts of the specification that are currently included are HTML5 audio and video tags.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to embed it inside an `<object>` tag.

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" item-prop="image" id="[give any id]" data=" [mention your file name] "></object>
```

e.g

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" item-prop="image" id="svgImage" data="images/svgImage.svg"></object>
```

I think this should do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Even with all the other advice on this page I couldn't get it to work (even in Safari).

So I found a working example at:

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/3/35/Starbucks_Coffee_Logo.svg

and copied the file to my own site. Still no luck, so I had a look at that file and my own using Rex Swain's HTTP viewer:

http://www.rexswain.com/httpview.html

The difference became obvious. **My svg was being served as text/html**, and the **Starbucks logo was being served as image/svg+xml**.

The solution was to change the header by adding:

```
addtype image/svg+xml .svg
```

to the .htaccess file.