# svg is not displaying in safari mobile

Tags: mobile, safari, svg

I'm experimenting with javascript animation of svg and queueing them for display, first attempts are here: [link](http://www.stretchsketch.com) It runs in the FOCS (firefox, chrome, opera, safari) browsers but not in Safari mobile (ipad/iphone) I'm aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504942/mobile-safari-svg-problem)  question but it hasn't helped me so far (the namespace is already in the different svg files, and I experimented with the doc type).

Answer (score -1):

This had nothing to do with svg rendering, but i was using the relative new js function `.bind()` which caused errors. In the meanwhile I learned how to switch on the debug console for mobile safari and this helped me to pinpoint the problem. [Here is the solution!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: Your "solution" is the "bind" page on mozilla. Is that right? Do you mean your solution is to implement the "bind" func?