# Why is this simple SVG not working on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, svg

I am not able to render a simple SVG rectangle on an iPhone running iOS 4.2.1. The code is directly taken from the w3schools tutorial [here](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/tryit.asp?filename=trysvg_rect) or you can try it from my server [here](http://archfirst.org/apps/svg-rect/). I understand that iOS supported SVG starting from version 2.1, so this should work! What am I missing?

Needless to say that the exact same document is rendered correctly on my desktop browsers and also on an iPad.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504942/mobile-safari-svg-problem.  You're also begging for a W3Fools link, but I ain't gonna do it ;)

Comment: I don't understand that answer. As far as I can tell, they are asking to change the extension of the document from .html to .xml and it will work? I am writing an html5 application and hence can't change the doctype or the document extension.

Comment: As far as I understand it you have to add the xmlns attribute to the svg tag (`"xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"`)

Comment: I have that already, so that's not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you need to set the content type as xml in older versions of Safari and Firefox to serve inline SVG (you can, however, use it in an `img` tag is you don't need to access its DOM). If you don't want change the `doctype` or the extension you can let the web server handle it. In Apache you would place an .htaccess file in your document root and put...

```
AddType application/xhtml+xml .html
```

I'm not sure if this causes any side effects elsewhere. You could only serve it to older versions of Safari with some rewrite conditions, but I'm not too familiar with the syntax to give you a straight answer.

You can see your file served as xhtml here:

http://duopixel.com/stack/svg.html

Comment: Very interesting! I was able to get this example to work by adding the .htaccess file as you suggest, but for a more complex example the browsers started complaining about xhtml parsing errors (including the iPhone). Of course the file is not xhtml, it is html5 - so that's understandable.