# How can I solve this enlarged SVG rendering problem that only occurs on iPhones?

Tags: css, ios, svg

See the Chevrons in the attached images.  The first one is from a desktop Chrome browser.  It renders this way in the standard desktop browsers including Safari.  It also renders this way in Chrome dev tools device simulations including iPhone 12, and on real Android devices.

The second image shows how it renders on a real iPhone 12 and device simulations (such as lambdatest or browserstack).  The Chevron is at least 100% larger.

I've tried adding a position: relative style to both the chevron and its parent div with no luck.  Reference the answer by Aaron Krauss at [Mobile Safari SVG Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504942/mobile-safari-svg-problem) .

I don't know of a way to check the css from a simulation, let alone an iPhone.  Any advice on how to do that or what to try for a fix?

[image: Correctly rendering in most browsers]

[image: Enlarged on iPhone]

Markup:

```
<div id="alert-message" class="warning" aria-live="assertive">
<div id="alert-message-header" data-bind="click: toggleAlertMessageBody()">
    <span id="alert-icon"></span>        
    <span id="alert-header-text">Other shops may have earlier availability.</span>        
    <button id="alert-chevron" name="alert-chevron-btn" type="button"></button>
</div>
<div id="alert-message-body" >Body</div>
```

css:

```
#alert-message {
margin-bottom: 32px;
border: 1px solid;
border-radius: 5px;
font-family: 'Roboto';
font-style: normal;
}
#alert-message #alert-message-header {
display: -webkit-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
min-height: 41px;
font-weight: 500;
cursor: pointer;
line-height: 26px;
position: relative;
}
#alert-message #alert-message-body {
margin: 0 15px;
padding: 8px 16px 12px 16px;
border-top: 1px solid;
color: #525656;
line-height: 26px;
font-weight: 400;
}
#alert-message.warning,
#alert-message.warning-info {
background-color: #fef6e8;
border-color: #e86421;
}
#alert-message.warning #alert-message-body,
#alert-message.warning-info #alert-message-body {
border-color: #e86421;
}
#alert-message.warning #alert-icon {
background: url("/Shared/images/alert-circle-yellow.svg") no-repeat;
min-width: 15px;
max-height: 25px;
background-position: center;
background-size: 100% auto;
}
#alert-message #alert-header-text {
padding: 0 10px;
color: #000000;
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
        flex-grow: 1;
}
#alert-message.warning #alert-chevron {
background: url("/Shared/images/chevron-up-yellow.svg") no-repeat;
min-width: 15px;
max-height: 25px;
background-position: center;
background-size: 100% auto;
}
#alert-message #alert-chevron {
position: relative;
border: none;
transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
transition: transform 0.3s;
}
#alert-message #alert-chevron.collapsed {
-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
        transform: rotate(180deg);
}
#alert-message b {
color: #000000;
}
```

Tried replacing the min-height on #alert-message-header div that contains the chevron with height: 48px;.  No change.

SVG:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="15" height="9" viewBox="0 0 15 9">
<path fill="#E86421" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M7.5 0a.806.806 0 0 0-.593.265L.246 7.455a.957.957 0 0 0 0 1.28.796.796 0 0 0 1.185 0l6.07-6.55 6.068 6.55a.796.796 0 0 0 1.186 0 .957.957 0 0 0 0-1.28L8.093.265A.806.806 0 0 0 7.5 0"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: we'd really need to see the chevron markup.

Comment: Could you please send the css code ?

Comment: Do you have the size of the SVG explicitly stated? I believe I ran into the same problem in one of my own projects, and defining an explicit size (width: 2em; height: auto; for example) fixed it.

Comment: Added html and css

Comment: Please add your svg markup as well. Quite likely, you can fix the problem by setting a default `height` or `width`. safari has problems calculating a bounding box if only min/max-width (or height) properties are set.

Comment: @herrstrietzel not sure what you mean  by SVG markup - the #alert-message.warning #alert-chevron css rule above should have what you mean.  I did just try setting specific height and width to 15, but that didn't appear to have an effect.

Comment: we can't see whats **"inside"** your referenced  "chevron-up-yellow.svg" (relative paths...). So please add a snippet with the chevrons markup/content.

Comment: Added the SVG markup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the "why" but removing the background-size: 100% auto; from the chevron (and keeping it for the alert-icon) fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

- You may debug the simulator with safary, to do that, first add the devtools on the computer's safary, you can enableit on `preferences/advanced`, **mark the checkbox at the bottom of the screen**.
- Then navigate to your web page on the simulator's browser
- Now back to the safary of your computer
- Go to the main menu/development
- There, search for your simulator's name and click on this option.
  (The safary sould open the development tools for the simulator's page).

I hope this could help you :D

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried Chrome dev tools and the simulator in this case is only contained in a <canvas> element.

Comment: As it turns out, lambdatest at least offered a dev tools feature within the simulator, and this is ultimately what allowed me to discover the solution.